# Can't understand the issue

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to javascript and can't understand the output `hi`*6. Why six times? Everything is fine if I use indexOf structure.
Here is the code:

```js
let a = 5
let processed = []
let f = Infinity;
while (true) {
  if (a < f && !(a in processed)) {
    console.log("hi")
    processed.push(a);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: why you are using infinity??

Answer (score 3):

You have two conditions.

`a < f` will *always* be true because neither variable ever changes

`!(a in processed)` is true until `processed[5]` (the 6th value in the array) is a true value.

`push` adds an item to the array

When there are 6 items the second condition is no longer met

Answer (score 1):

index in arrays start at 0, and that is why your code gets executed 6 times (0,1,2,3,4,5) until the condition is met